# Laravel model Many to Many using attach function

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to add information to my pivot table using the attach function of my model, provided by Laravel.

The models includes this function:

```
public function incidentTypes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\IncidentType', 'incident_incident_type', 'incident_id', 'incident_type_id');
}
```

The pivot table is created and comprises of two FKs. One related to the table `incidents` and one to the table `incident_types`

When I use tinker to test the setup, I use this function call:

```
$incident->incidentTypes()->attach('I100');
```

**Pivot Table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('incident_incident_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('incident_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('incident_id')->references('incident_id')->on('incidents');

            $table->string('incident_type_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('incident_type_id')->references('incident_type_id')->on('incident_types');
        });
    }
```

The **Incident Class**

```
class Incident extends Model {

    use EventGenerator;

    protected $table = 'incidents';
    protected $fillable = ['incident_id', 'incident_type', 'location', 'street', 'city', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'date', 'time', 'incident_archived'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function set($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function responders() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Classes\Responder');
    }

    public function incidentTypes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\IncidentType', 'incident_incident_type', 'incident_id', 'incident_type_id');
    }

    // set fields on the eloquent object and save to database
    // raise event that the incident was created.
    public function createIncident($command) {
        $this->incident_id = $command->incidentId;
        $this->save();
        $this->raise(new IncidentWasPosted($this));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**The IncidentType Class**

```
class IncidentType extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['incident_id', 'incident_type_id'];

    public function incidents() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classes\Incident', 'incident_incident_type', 'incident_id', 'incident_type_id');
    }
}
```

**The Error**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead`.`incident_incident_type`, CONSTRAINT `incident_incident_type_incident_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`incident_id`) REFERENCES `incidents` (`incident_id`)) (SQL: insert into `incident_incident_type` (`incident_id`, `incident_type_id`) values (0, AED))'
```

Comment: What is your database schema for these other two tables? Incidents has an incident_id?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Why does your IncidentType have an incident_id? Isn't this association what the many-to-many incident_incident_type table is for?

Comment: maybe I should call it differently. It is more like a unique reference number for a ticket.

Comment: Gotcha- because right now I'm not sure which id is the incident id and which is the incident id =.=

Comment: The thing is: I just added a regular incrementing id integer field as PK on my tables (all of them) and now everything works fine. But when I want to use custom PKs like a string value the functions like "belongsToMany" can't handle that anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94758/discussion-between-sesc360-and-mikel-bitson).

Comment: So wouldn't it be better not to use "surrogate PKs" but the natural ones like the "incident Id" which is unique? But when I do this, all the laravel functions complain that they cannot work properly anymore. BelongsToMany spits out a SQL statement that is searching for an "id" column (which would be the default one) when I am using incident_id as my PK. Is there any where to tell the model what to look for?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure why eloquent wouldn't allow the custom primary keys- but it's always a good idea to use an auto-increment as the primary key as that data type is much more easily indexed by SQL systems. I'd just use a normal auto-increment ID for both tables.

Comment: Ok... well with the auto-inc ID it works very well... hm... I thought natural PKs over surrogate ones when designing a database?

Comment: You can tell eloquent which column the keys should be in. This is done by passing it to the belongsToMany call. Options are: belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null) - I see you used this in your first chunk of code, but not in the models you posted later?

Comment: Oh I tried this, but it doesn't work for some reason. It still wants to search for an 'id' field. hm

Comment: I'll continue to help in chat if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the create() method to get an instance of the saved model then use that model to attach your incidentType.  For example:

```
$incident = Incident::create(['property_name'=>'property_value']);
$incident->incidentTypes()->attach('I100');
```

Otherwise, after doing save(), retrieve the saved model then attach your incidentType.